# vbox overflow when using TitleGM causing a blank page to preceed the title page

Tags: formatting, titles

I'm getting a blank page that precedes my title page, and I suspect that it is due to the vbox overflow warning that I'm getting.  The problem is that I don't know how to properly adjust the vbox setting!  Can anyone help?  Here an example document that shows the problem:

```
\documentclass[10pt,ebook,oneside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage[scaled]{berasans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{framed}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\fi

\chapterstyle{madsen}
\pagestyle{ruled}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\linespread{1.2}
\restylefloat{figure}

\newlength{\drop}
\newcommand*{\titleGM}{
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begingroup
  \drop = 0.1\textheight
  \vspace*{\baselineskip}
  \vfill
  \hbox{ 
    \hspace*{0.2\textwidth} 
    \rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\textheight-28pt\relax} % Vertical line
    \hspace*{0.05\textwidth} 
    \parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{ 
      \vbox{
        \vspace{\drop}
    {\noindent\HUGE\bfseries Growing The\\[0.5\baselineskip]Money Tree}\\[2    \baselineskip]
    {\Large\itshape Cultivating Financial Freedom One Leaf At A Time}\\[.37    \baselineskip] 
        {\Large \textsc{John Svazic}}\par 
        \vspace{0.5\textheight} 
        {\noindent ARM Trading Press}\\[\baselineskip]
      }% end of vbox
    }
    }
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\titleGM
\frontmatter
\mainmatter
It was a dark and stormy night...
\backmatter
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprits were `\vspace{0.5\textheight}` and `\linespread{1.2}`. I reduced the length used for the `\vspace` and moved the `\linespread` line somewhere after building the title. I also removed some spurious blank spaces (by inserting `%` at appropriate locations (I hope I have remove all of them)), and changed to roman font for "John Svazic" (latin modern doesn't provide small caps in the sans serif family):

```
\documentclass[10pt,ebook,oneside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage[scaled]{berasans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{framed}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\fi

\chapterstyle{madsen}
\pagestyle{ruled}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{figure}

\newlength{\drop}
\newcommand*{\titleGM}{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begingroup
  \drop=0.1\textheight
  \vspace*{\baselineskip}
  \vfill
  \hbox{% 
    \hspace*{0.2\textwidth}%
    \rule{1pt}{\dimexpr\textheight-28pt\relax} % Vertical line
    \hspace*{0.05\textwidth}%
    \parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{%
      \vbox{%
        \vspace{\drop}
    {\noindent\HUGE\bfseries Growing The\\[0.5\baselineskip]Money Tree}\\[2    \baselineskip]
    {\Large\itshape Cultivating Financial Freedom One Leaf At A Time}\\[.37    \baselineskip] 
        {\Large\rmfamily\textsc{John Svazic}}\par 
        \vspace{0.47\textheight}
        \noindent ARM Trading Press
        \vspace*{\baselineskip}
      }% end of vbox
    }%
    }
\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\titleGM
\linespread{1.2}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter
It was a dark and stormy night...
\backmatter
\end{document}
```

[image]